# How can I use Database Relations in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

I need to do a software for a "restaurant" and it needs to be able to calculate prices for the dishes that need to be cooked taking the prices from a list of ingredients. I imagine that the Dishes model would need a field called ingredients or one field for each ingredient (?), but i dont know how it would fetch the Ingredients model for the prices for each ingredient and calculate the total based on the quantity that needs to be cooked. What would be the best method? Like to have a template that shows the price of each ingredient with its quantity and the total of all the ingredients.

Comment: any attempts so far?

Comment: @chrisRubiano please let me know I my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Dish` is composed of many `Ingredient` s  and each `Ingredient` will be used in many `Dish`es so the following suggestion will be proper for your problem

```
class Dish(models.Model):
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2) 

class DishIngredient(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```